# google maps zoom in with phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, geolocation

I am working with google maps using phonegap. I have added the map on my screen with the code below. But the problem is when I want to zoom in using my two fingers and dragin them it does not zoom. How can I add this feature?

Here is my code.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
onSuccess();
}


function onSuccess () {
var map = document.getElementById('map');
var mapOptions = {
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(37.7831, -122.4039),
    zoom : 12,
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var gmap = new google.maps.Map(map, mapOptions);

var markerOptions = {
    position : new google.maps.LatLng(37.7831, -122.4039)
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
marker.setMap(gmap);

var infoWindowOptions = {
    content : 'Here I am'
};

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
google.maps.event.addEventListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});

}

function onError (error) {
alert('code: ' + error.code     + '\n' +
    'message'+ error.message
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at going Native with a mapkit plugin.
That will add Pinch to Zoom. 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/MapKit

Note though: Might change with IOS6